# map iterator, error reading character of string

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, unordered-map

I am trying to do partial match in a map with prefix.

my `keys` look something like: `"ABCD efg,1234"`

my `values` look something like: `"qqwe,123123,asdad,2000,323232"`

think the string i pass to match against the key is `"ABCD efg"`

```
  NOTE: the `map` deceleration is elsewhere. It is declered like the following: 
       std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> umap;

 Code:

std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator Account::FindPrefix(const std::string& search_for)
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator got = umap.lower_bound(search_for);

    if (got != umap.end())
    {
        const std::string& key = got->first;
        if (key.compare(0, search_for.size(), search_for) == 0)
            return got;
    }
    return umap.end();
}
```

The code compiled, but always returned `umap.end()`, and never returned `got`, so i used the debugger and i noticed, that the `constant iterator got` gets a value of `(<Error reading characters of string>,<Error reading characters of string>)`

NOTE: I did check to make sure i am feeding the values correctly to the `map`, seems to be fine as i can see it get populated.

NOTE2: Kabanus suggested to output got, before the if statement. when it reaches`std::cout<<got->first;` program crashes and i get the following massage:

```
Exception thrown at 0x57EF65F6 (msvcp140d.dll) in BankManagment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD.
```

EDIT:
I do not know why compiler did not catch the use of lower_bound with un-ordered map
[image]

EDIT:
Following is the error massage to `decltype` (requested in comments of the post)
[image]

Comment: There is a chance the error message is from the debugger, not what actually happens. Try outputting got.first (before the if) - make sure you're expecting a match.

Comment: @kabanus I followed up with your suggestion and added the result to the bottom of the post. when i researched, it was noted that 'lowerbound' should be able to match 'key = "ABC 1234" ' with 'string = "ABC" '.

Comment: `unordered_map` does not have a lower_bound method.  What is the type of `umap`?

Comment: @Curious i did not think about that, container is not ordered, so it can not have less that, or greater than -> lower_bound cant work; correct? :-(

Comment: Yeah, but what is concerning me here is how the code compiled in the first place, how are you able to assign an iterator of a non `unordered_map` class to a `unordered_map::iterator`?

Comment: If you used `std::lower_bound` it requires a sorted sequence, which `unordered_map` won't give you.

Comment: @Curious I added a snap of my VS to show compilation.

Comment: @dirty_feri can you also post something that tells us what the type of `umap` is?

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank you for your response, I wrongly assumed it can be used as the compiler did not complain.

Comment: @Curious , sorry I am not sure if i am fully understanding you.  'std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> umap;' and belongs to a class named Account

Comment: @dirty_feri in that case how are you able to call a method on it that does not exist?

Comment: write this piece of code in the global namespace `template <typename...> struct WhichType;` and then in your code that assigns the iterator write this right before the iterator assignment `WhichType<decltype(umap)>{};` and tell us what the type of `umap` is if you are not sure,  it might be something else

Comment: @Curious your dealing with an idiot, so i get the error incomplete type is not allowed. I defined 'WhichType' in the global namespace, and put 'WhichType' in the function posted above, right before the constant iterator deceleration.

Comment: @dirty_feri can you post the entire incomplete type error?  It should contain a hint about what the type of `umap` actually is

Comment: @Curious I added it to the end of the post.

Comment: @dirty_feri it seems like your code is not compiling, because for one there is an error saying "not all paths return a value".  Meaning that what you are trying to run is an old version of your code or just something else entirely

Comment: @Curious that shows up as warning, without the chunk of code i added when you asked the code compiles. I posted a snapshot. At least It says build succ..

Comment: @dirty_feri ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ if you can paste a piece of code that we can compile ourselves I can try and help, otherwise I am out of ideas

Comment: @Curious I can post the entire code :-D its very large tho. should i?

Comment: @dirty_feri ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I switched unordered_map to map, and problem is solved. I still dont understand why compiler does not catch it

Comment: The compiler does not catch it because it can't possibly know if your sequence is sorted or not. It's up to you to ensure that. `std::map` is automatically sorted so it will work, but you're better off using the built-in functions with that because they're more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `find` method: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/find/

If it was `std::map`, the lower bound would have marked either the item itself (if already there) or position at which it might be added ("insert hint"). It's good for efficient seek-or-insert operation (you don't need to traverse through the tree again). You are just emulating what `find` already does, here (that is to say, IF IT WAS `std::map`, again)...